# Error when using luaotfload-tool

Tags: luatex, fontspec, ubuntu

i am trying to install Myriad Pro at my Ubuntu PC to use it with Lualatex and fontspec. The font is correctly installed and can be used in LibreOffice.

```
fc-list | grep -i myriad
->
    Myriad Pro:style=Italic
    Myriad Pro:style=Bold
    Myriad Pro:style=Bold Italic
    Myriad Pro:style=Regular
```

When I'm trying to compile a .tex document with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Myriad Pro}
```

there is an error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "MyriadPro" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.57 \setmainfont{Myriad Pro}
```

I the tried to use luaotfload-tool and this error appears:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/luaotfload-tool:538: '=' expected near 'found'
```

Same when running mkluatexfontdb. What can i do now ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your write-up is a bit confusing -- you say the font `Myriad Pro` is installed, yet it looks like you're trying to load `Minion Pro` via the instruction `\setmainfont{Minion Pro}`. Did you maybe want to write `\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}`?

Comment: Okay, Copy-Paste mistake. In the end i need both fonts, but the error is the same for both.

Comment: no problem here with `luaotfload-tool --find="Minion Pro"` and version 2.4-4 of `luaotfload-tool`

Comment: My `luaotfload-tool` says it is version 2.4-4 too. :(

Comment: run `luaotfload-tool --update --force`

Comment: This gives me `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/luaotfload-tool:538: '=' expected near 'found'` too..

Comment: Delete the cache files under `/.../2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/` and try again

Comment: Does not change anything..

Comment: Perhaps your version of the script got corrupted: Try to reinstall luaotfload with tlmgr. If the problem persist you perhaps found a bug which only shows on your system. Try to get more information e.g. by running luaotfload-tool with -vvv.

Comment: I removed luaotfload-tool with tlmgr and reinstalled it, but the error isn't gone. `-vvv` produces the same error.

Comment: Possibly caused by an interfering older version of Luatex. What does ``luatex --version`` say? If it’s older than 0.75 then you should update it. Or fix your ``$PATH``.